# Divs with similar structure would all act when only clicked on one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, django

I use div to show a heading and a paragraph. I include a thumb up image on the bottom right corner. My intent is that when thumb up is clicked, it will change color and scale. However, with my code, when click on one thumb up, all thumbs would act the same way.

I'm using Django template, here is a mock-up. I think something is wrong with my js file, please let me know how to fix it. Many thanks.

```js
var $icon = $(".icon");
$icon.on('click', function() {
  if ($icon.closest("div").hasClass('anim')) {
    $icon.closest("div").removeClass('anim');
  } else {
    $icon.closest("div").addClass('anim');
  }
});
```

```css
.icon-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.icon-wrapper .icon {
  color: #90A4AE;
}

.icon-wrapper i {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.icon-wrapper.anim .icon {
  color: #39CCCC;
}

.icon-wrapper.anim i {
  animation: icon-animation cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 1.2s;
}

@keyframes icon-animation {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="things">
  <div class="thing">
    <div class="icon-wrapper">
      <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></span>
    </div>
    <h2>Wachet auf, ruft uns die Stimme</h2>
    <p>Wachet auf, ruft uns die Stimme (Awake, calls the voice to us),[1] BWV 140,[a] also known as Sleepers Wake, is a church cantata by Johann Sebastian Bach, regarded as one of his most mature and popular sacred cantatas. He composed the chorale cantata
      in Leipzig for the 27th Sunday after Trinity and first performed it on 25 November 1731.</p>
    <small>Jan. 2, 2018, 6:38 a.m.</small>
  </div>

  <div class="thing">
    <div class="icon-wrapper">
      <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></span>
    </div>
    <h2>Wachet auf, ruft uns die Stimme</h2>
    <p>Wachet auf, ruft uns die Stimme (Awake, calls the voice to us),[1] BWV 140,[a] also known as Sleepers Wake, is a church cantata by Johann Sebastian Bach, regarded as one of his most mature and popular sacred cantatas. He composed the chorale cantata
      in Leipzig for the 27th Sunday after Trinity and first performed it on 25 November 1731.</p>
    <small>Jan. 2, 2018, 6:38 a.m.</small>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of you're adding the class to a closest `$icon`, this selector cover all `.icon` of the page. Refactor your code this way:

```
var $icon = $(".icon");
 $icon.on('click', function() {
 if ($(this).closest("div").hasClass('anim')) {
   $(this).closest("div").removeClass('anim');
 } else {
   $(this).closest("div").addClass('anim');
 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But this works only when I click thumb up for the first time. When I click a different thumb up, nothing happens. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
var $icon = $(".icon");
$icon.on('click', function() {
  var $closest = $(this).closest('div'); // you need to use $(this) for currently clicked icon

  $closest.toggleClass('anim'); // just use toggleClass instead of an if (unless you have other functionality in the if)
});
```